# Why jQuery autocomplete select not work?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

When I input 5 in the customer_code input area. It list the values.The problem is that when I select an entry, the 'id' value should show in the customer_name area.But it didn't!

```
[{"id":"5","code":"code005","name":"\u9867\u5ba2\u540d005"},{"id":"15","code":"code015","name":"\u9867\u5ba2\u540d015"},]
```

the json return by php is like above.and

```
$(function() {
        $( "#customer_code" ).autocomplete({
        source:  function( request, response ) {
            $.ajax({
                url: "/management/order/auto",
                dataType: "json",
                data: {code: request.term},
                success: function(data) {
                     var suggestions = [];
                    $.each(data, function(i, val) {
                        suggestions.push({
                            label: val.code,
//                          label: val.name,
                        });
                    });
                    response( suggestions );
                },
            });
        },
        select: function(e, ui) {
            alert(ui.item.name);
//          $('#customer_name').val(ui.item.name);
//          $('#customer_name').val(ui.item.value.name);
//          return false;
        },
        });
    });
```

my html page is like this

```
<?php echo Form::input('customer_name', Arr::get($basic, 'customer_name'), array('id' => 'customer_name')); ?>
<?php echo Form::input('customer_code', Arr::get($basic, 'customer_code'), array('id' => 'customer_code')); ?>
```

Comment: the line `$('#customer_name').val(ui.item.name);` should have `ui.item.name` or `ui.item.id`?

Comment: Note that, as an array of objects, the [`source` is expected to contain `label` and `value`](http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#option-source), not `name`.

Comment: I edit with a alert it shows nothing, why the select function not perform?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `select` callback is currently part of the settings for the `$.ajax()` request, which won't use it:

```
// ...
    $.ajax({
        url: "/management/order/auto",
        // ...
        success: function (data) {
            // ...
        },
        select: function (e, ui) {
            // ...
        }
    });
// ...
```

It should instead be part of the options for `.autocomplete()`, outside of the `function` for `source`.

```
$( "#customer_code" ).autocomplete({
    source: function( request, response ) {
        $.ajax({
            url: "/management/order/auto",
            // ...
            success: function () {
                // ...
            }
        });
    },
    select: function (e, ui) {
        // ...
    }
})
```

Comment: I have changed it to what you said, but it alert 'undefined'.

Comment: @さむらい Try `alert(ui.item.label);`. The objects being `push`ed to `suggestions` don't have `name`s, just `label`s. So, `undefined` is expected. And, amending my previous comment: the objects given to `response()` should have *at least* `label` and `value` properties, but they can also have `name`s or any other property desired.